# How to Flash (Chrome or Firefox) hardware accelerated decoding? Something instead?

Tags: ati, video, google-chrome, flash

What can I do to get GPU to work on decoding Flash video?

At `chrome://gpu` `Graphics Feature Status` page I see all stuff green OK like `Video Decode: Hardware accelerated`, yet Flash `nerd statistics` tell me that decoding is done by software (yet rendering is accelerated).

I got not open source (additional) drivers for mobile ATI HD 7340. Had to change one Chrome `flag` to make rendering accelerated. What about decoding?

EDIT: I lowered CPU usage for Totem via Direct2D http://www.webupd8.org/2010/04/how-to-enable-direct2d-acceleration-in.html, but no changes in Flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE

---

For weaker hardware or decent hardware but desire for real 24 FPS web-embedded videos I suggest `minitube-ubuntu`, resoned below. Minitube can play videos from Youtube without using `Flash` and having `Graphics User Interface`, that is better decoding performance or less system resources taken for the action. I have also noticed difference in FPS (= no screen tearing or slideshow) while Flash was showing FALSE 0 dropped frames... The only problem I found is no Youtube account support, however subscribe works fine.

---

You can get `minitube-ubuntu` at `Software Center`.

`gstreamer` package or workaround may be needed:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/kde4/plugins/phonon_backend /usr/lib/qt4/plugins/phonon_backend
```

.

Other issues fixes: http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube/faq

---

For videos not hosted on Youtube there is `youtube-dl` supporting variety of sites. But without `GUI`, command termianl program.

---

Spec

```
CPU 2x 1700 MHz
APU AMD E2-1800 driven by fglrx-updates, VESA
Ubuntu v14.04
Chrome v36.0.1985.125
Flash v14.0.0.145 /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so
```

---

Performance

`youtube.com` `HTML5` video 480p taking 70% CPU and false 24 FPS (I think Flash renders OK but Chrome FPS is lower and my eyes are not satisfied while screen is tearing)

`minitube-ubuntu` 1080p taking 70% CPU and true 24 FPS

Answer (score 0):

I have increased `Flash` performance in `Chrome` by removing `fglrx` drivers and installing default `xorg` instead. Even time spent on compiling special build of `fglrx` didn't help, `Chrome GPU process` was crashing which results less `Flash` performance.